# Azure: New-AzRoleAssignment Input string was not in a correct format - error with double parsing... without any number

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I have a strange problem with my PowerShell script to create Azure user accounts.

Executing command

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName 'Contributor' -ObjectId "$Usr.Id" -ResourceGroupName "$rgname"
```

Results in exception:

```
New-AzRoleAssignment : Input string was not in a correct format.
At myscript.ps1:151 char:5
+     New-AzRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName 'Contributor' -ObjectId  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzRoleAssignment], FormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureRoleAssignmentCommand
```

I've extracted stacktrace for this exception, and it looks like this:

```
at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureRoleAssignmentCommand.ExecuteCmdlet()
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
```

Which is super strange - I'm not using any double number here. I've dig into source code for [NewAzureRoleAssignmentCommand](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/src/Resources/Resources/RoleAssignments/NewAzureRoleAssignmentCommand.cs) - but there is no `System.Number.ParseDouble` call there.

Only thing related to double is `-ConditionVersion`, but I don't want to use any Coditions.

What I should check next? I'm not an advanced Azure/Powershell user, so any suggestions are welcomed!

edit:
I've tried running command manually using same parameter values, with and without quotation marks - every time I get same error

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName 'Contributor' -ObjectId f01b4003-8a47-4a9d-8935-cd000c8cd9c5 -ResourceGroupName myValidResourceGrupName
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Azure Cloud Shell to check whether the problem might be local to your machine.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the double quotes that are around $usr.id

If you'd only have a string like:

```
$usr = <GUID goes here>
```

then you could pass "$usr". But in this case, you're trying to access the Id property of the $usr object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortuntelly, it didn't help. I tried it before. Exception stays exatbly th same. If I try to run this command manually, not in script - I get same exception.

Comment: That is quite strange, I just tried the same thing on my end, and it worked like a charm. I would ask whether you're sure if $usr.id and $rgname hold proper values, but if you say that the same thing happens when you run it manually, maybe you're running an outdated version of some PS module?
When running the script have you tried outputting the values before running the action with write-host?
Another thing to try might be Cloud Shell. If it works there, it would mean that the problem is local to your machine.

Comment: Azure Cloud Shell was a perfect hint - thank you! Problem in fact must be in my locally installed tools, but I'm good enough with using Cloud Shell. Could you post it as separate answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: there you go :)

Answer (score 1):

I would try getting your with [`Get-AzRoleDefinition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azroledefinition?view=azps-4.6.0). I tend to get the objects for everything and use the IDs. This works for me.

```bsh
$Role = Get-AzRoleDefinition -Name Contributor
$ResourceGroup = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name "ResourceGroupName"
$User = Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName "User-UPN-Here"
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $User.Id -RoleDefinitionId $Role.Id -Scope $ResourceGroup.ResourceId
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried, but unfortunatelly, it's still not working. However, @Radoslaw Wiankowski provided a workaround with Azure Cloud Shell, so I'm good now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  This script used to work:

```
$qa = get-azadgroup -displayname qa;
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $qa.Id -RoleDefinitionName Owner -ResourceGroupName RG-QA
```

Started getting this error on one computer but not the other.  When I checked the modules version for az.resources, I had 2.1.0, 2.4.0 and 2.5.0.  After removing versions 2.4.0 and 2.5.0, the script worked.  I have the language of Powershell set to French.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/13096 it's this issue if anyone else runs into this issue. Workaround as above is to use 2.1.0 of Az.resources but should be fixed soon.