# Query blob storage with Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem?

Tags: azure-powershell

Our powershell test harness used to use Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem to list blobs found in non data lake storage accounts. Today I updated the powershell and Az module versions they were locked at, and now when issuing the command (specifying a Filesystem container, and context), the following error is returned:

```
Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

I'm assuming something has changed, and this function cannot process a result from non data lake storage compatibly anymore.

For one reason or another, a while back we changed from using Get-AzStorageBlob. So interested to know if there's any solution to be able to continue working with this call, rather than to deviate from Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem where required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the workaround to list the  sub directories and files in a directory or Filesystem from an Azure storage account using the `Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem` .

- *To do that we must have* [**`enabled Hierarchical Namespace`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstorageaccount?view=azps-8.0.0#example-5-create-a-storage-account-with-hierarchical-namespace-enabled) .

Then you will get something like below example;

[image]

***NOTE:-*** If you are using existing storage which has not enabled Hierarchical Namespace then you need to upgrade that storage account by doing the below steps:

[image]

*For more information please refer the below links:-*

- **MS DOC**| [**`Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azdatalakegen2childitem?view=azps-8.0.0#examples) , [**`Get-AzStorageBlob`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblob?view=azps-8.0.0) .
- [**SO THREAD**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63598486/azure-new-azroleassignment-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-error-wit) *FOR SIMILAR ISSUE*.